# CAST inside LIKE in SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE AccessUser
(
    `AccessUserID` int, 
    `AccessUserName` varchar(255), 
    `AccessUserType` int, 
    `AccessUserGroups` varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO AccessUser
(   `AccessUserID`, 
    `AccessUserName`, 
    `AccessUserType`, 
    `AccessUserGroups`
)
VALUES
    (1, 'Group 1', 2, ''),
    (2, 'Group 2', 2, ''),
    (3, 'John', 5, '@1@'),
    (4, 'Nick', 5, '@1@@2@');
```

**QUESTION: How do i get this result (based on `AccessUserGroups`, which refers to `AccessUserID`)?**

```
| NAME | FIRMNAME |
|------|----------|
| John |  Group 1 |
| Nick |  Group 1 |
| Nick |  Group 2 |
```

**I have tried something like this, but i get an error:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Empl.AccessUserName AS Name,
Firm.AccessUserName AS FirmName
FROM AccessUser AS Firm, AccessUser AS Empl
WHERE Empl.AccessUserType = 5
AND Empl.AccessUserGroups LIKE ('%@' + CAST(Firm.AccessUserID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '@%')
ORDER BY Empl.AccessUserName ASC
```

**Error:**

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"
    `'VARCHAR(10)) + '@%') ORDER BY Empl.AccessUserName ASC'`
    at line 6:...[same sql again]

Comment: MySQL does not support VARCHAR in the CAST, use CHAR instead http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34564

Comment: Thanks, that worked! No errors now. But also no results! Can you help me with this?

Comment: SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b2eb/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the cast is implicit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Empl.AccessUserName AS Name,
Firm.AccessUserName AS FirmName
FROM AccessUser AS Firm, AccessUser AS Empl
WHERE Empl.AccessUserType = 5
AND Empl.AccessUserGroups LIKE CONCAT('%@', Firm.AccessUserID, '@%')
ORDER BY Empl.AccessUserName ASC;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d242d/2)**

Comment: Thanks GarethD. Next time I'll use CONCAT in MySQL - Unfortunately I've just found out that it is a SQL Server i'm on!

Comment: Your query [works fine on SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ecae7/1), and SQL Server 2012 and later support the use of [CONCAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh231515.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately it's SQL Server 2008 as far as I can see, so no support for CONCAT :(

Comment: It's not the end of the world though, since SQL Server 2008 is capable of casting to varchar, the only drawback is that your code is not portable.